# How to map json array elements to option selected in drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a json array like this

```
{Id:[1,2,4,5,8,9,14,22,10,11,12,13,20,21,28,30,31,15,23,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,41,16,24,42,43,48,49,17,25,58,59,61,62,63,64,66,67,68,18,26,69,70,74,75,19,27,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,108,109,110,111,120]}
```

and want to select corresponding id when an option is selected from select tag which is also dynamic i.e also a json array which is displayed in select tag option as

```
            <select id="list">
            <option>--Select--</option>`enter code here`
            <option>List gets updated by the json array</option>
           </select>
```

and I have to do it using jQuery/javascript..any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to iterate and generate [option element using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes). Attach **[`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change)** event handler to listen the event.

```js
var data = {
  Id: [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 14, 22, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 28, 30, 31, 15, 23, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 41, 16, 24, 42, 43, 48, 49, 17, 25, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 18, 26, 69, 70, 74, 75, 19, 27, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 108, 109, 110, 111, 120]
};

$('#list').append(
  data.Id.map(function(v) {
    return $('<option/>', {
      value: v,
      text: v
    })
  })
).change(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Since you need to get id based on the option selected update your code as follows. Where you can use **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method to get the index of the selected element.

```js
var data = {
  "StoreName": ["10001 Main ST", "10002 Part1", "10004 MyStore1", "10005 M STR", "10008 Centro", "10009 MyStore 02", "1001 G", "1001 H", "10010 Store main ROAD", "10011 Central M Store", "10012 En Department", "10013 M Station", "10014 Test Center", "10015 SubStore1", "10016 AA", "10018 M part #", "10019 Test A - 26032016", "1002 B", "1002 I", "10020 Test Central B "],
  Id: [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 14, 22, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 28, 30, 31, 15, 23, 32, 3, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 41, 16, 24, 42, 43, 48, 49, 1, 25, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 4, 66, 67, 68, 18, 26, 69, 70, 74, 75, 19, 27, 82, 8, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 1, 108, 109, 110, 111, 10]
};
$('#storenm').append(data.StoreName.map(function(v) {
  // generate option with value and text content
  return $('<option>', {
    text: v,
    value: v
  })
})).change(function() {
  console.log(data.Id[data.StoreName.indexOf(this.value)])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id="storenm" name="name">
    <option>--Select--</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: select option already has list of things and when i select one of the option i    should be able to fetch the corresponding id as given above @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @ShreyaRawal :  what you mean by ___corresponding id___?

Comment: @ShreyaRawal :  what's your expected o/p?

Comment: When i select any of the options the id which is provided as {Id:[1,2,4,5,8,9,14,22,10,11,12,13,20,21,28,30,31,15,23,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,41,16,24,42,43,48,49,17,25,58,59,61,62,63,64,66,67,68,18,26,69,70,74,75,19,27,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,108,109,110,111,120]}
should be fetched automatically along with the option.

Comment: Please provide the link of your updated answer@Pranav C Balan

Comment: This is what I needed...:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @ShreyaRawal : glad to help :)

Comment: Is there any other alternative for it..since I cant declare the id json array along with the store name array

Comment: @ShreyaRawal :  there is no need to define both property in same object.....  even it's 2 different object no problem at all.... `idObj.Id[data.StoreName.indexOf(this.value)]`